# Fetch next value/row of a column having multiple rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

My table is like this::

```
+-------+-----------------+---+
 id     |  created             |
+-------+-----------------+---+
| 2sdv  | 2016-05-18 14:08:14 |
| 2sdv  | 2016-05-18 14:25:22 |
| 2sdv  | 2016-05-18 14:26:01 |
| 2sdv  | 2016-05-19 07:19:13 |
+-------+---------------------+
```

Lets say this id ='2sdv' created on these dates 
I want the ouput to be like this

```
+-------+-----------------+---+------+-----------------+
 id     |  created            | new_date
+-------+-----------------+---+------+-----------------+
| 2sdv  | 2016-05-18 14:08:14 | 2016-05-18 14:25:22    |
| 2sdv  | 2016-05-18 14:25:22 | 2016-05-18 14:26:01    |
| 2sdv  | 2016-05-18 14:26:01 | 2016-05-19 07:19:13    |
| 2sdv  | 2016-05-19 07:19:13 |
+-------+---------------------+------+-----------------+
```

In `Oracle` we can use `lead()` function but I want my query to be in `MySQL`.
how can I get next value of created date column in a new column in multiple rows fetch .

Comment: your question is not very clear.

Comment: You want the minimum y date greater than the corresponding x date. Because you also want the latest x date, this would be a LEFT JOIN

Comment: your id's would be unique or same??

Comment: In this particular case my id is same but i want to add a new column having next value of date created

Comment: This is not something MySQL is designed to be able to do. You should solve this problem outside MySQL. It's easily solved in a language like PHP for example

Comment: @Jester Absolute rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment above...

```
SELECT x.*
     , MIN(y.created) new_date -- the minimum y date...
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.id = x.id 
   AND y.created > x.created -- ... greater than the corresponding x date
 GROUP 
    BY x.id
     , x.created;
```